# How do I use a `match_pattern` of type `regex` to define an elasticsearch dynamic template

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to use a `regex` to match various `id` fields such `collection_id` so they are not analyed.

A simple regex `^.*_id$` is not working to match the fields.

```
{
  "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "system_ids": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match_pattern": "regex",
            "match": "^.*_id$",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
         }
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am testing this on elasticsearch 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, it turns out you need to add the regex to a capture group.
Using `^(.*_id)$` as the `match` worked. I have no idea why but it does.